# XSD not validating against xml

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I'm new to XSD and can't figure out why my XSD isn't validating. I'm getting the following errors:

s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'parametersInfo' is invalid. Element 'complexType' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'exception'. No child element is expected at this point.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service id="IServiceREST">
            <inherit>
                <parent>Remote</parent>
            </inherit>
            <package>com.module</package>
            <include>java.rmi.Remote</include>
            <include>java.net.*</include>
            <include>java.io.*</include>
            <abstract_method id="getContent">
                <visibility>public</visibility>
                <parameters>
                    <argument type="URL">url</argument>
                    <argument type="int">timeout</argument>
                </parameters>
                <throw>
                    <exception>MalformedURLException</exception>
                    <exception>IOException</exception>
                </throw>
                <return>String</return>
            </abstract_method>
            <abstract_method id="deleteUser">
                <visibility>public</visibility>
                <parameters>
                    <argument type="String">username</argument>
                </parameters>
                <return>void</return>
            </abstract_method>
</service>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="serviceInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="inherit" type="inheritInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="package" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="include" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="abstract_method" type="abstract_methodInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="inheritInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="parent" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="abstract_methodInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="visibility" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element type="parametersInfo" name="parameters" />    
            <xs:element type="throwInfo" name="throw" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="return" minOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" />
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="throwInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name ="exception" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="parametersInfo">
            <xs:complexType type="xs:string" name="argument">
             <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="URL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="timeout" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
             </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="service" type="serviceInfo"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Am I missing something? I wanted to make it easier by using complex types and referencing them to break it down...

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of type `parametersInfo` reads

```
<xs:complexType name="parametersInfo">
  <xs:complexType type="xs:string" name="argument">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="URL" type="xs:string" 
                  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="timeout" type="xs:integer" 
                  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:complexType>
```

The XSD `complexType` element cannot appear as a child of `complexType`.  I don't know what you were trying to do, but this is not the way to do it.

You may need to work through a tutorial or two on XSD.